# Aggregate by date and group and fill in missing dates in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with ID, a start date and an end date.

```
ID  start_date  end_date
1   01/01/2014  06/01/2014
2   10/01/2005  12/01/2015
3   08/01/2009  10/01/2012
...
```

I have another table with every event by ID with a date (truncated to month).

```
ID  month_year   amount
1   02/01/2014   100
1   03/01/2007   25
2   010/01/2010  50
...
```

I want to be able to get the monthly total by ID with the zero months added back in.

```
ID  month_year   amount
1   02/01/2007   100
1   03/01/2007   0
2   04/01/2007   0
...
```

Apologies if this is a basic question. It is very close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694040/how-to-generate-date-series-to-occupy-absent-dates-in-google-biqquery/38702850) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693016/fill-with-zeros-in-a-frequency-of-dates-group-by-month-and-year-in-big-query), but due to the size of the dataset it is important to only fill in zeros for each ID between the start_date and end_date. It is also like [enter link description here](http://this%20question), but I'm unable to translate that into big query. My code right now is off, but something like:

```
WITH data AS(
            SELECT * FROM `Table 11` AS t0
), all_months AS (
   SELECT month
   FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
     (SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM data)
     , (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM data)
     , INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
   ) AS month
)

SELECT DISTINCT ID month_year, 
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, month_year) AS sum_amount,   
FROM data AS t0
LEFT JOIN all_months AS t1
ON t0.month_year=t1.month
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.data` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '01/01/2014' start_date, '06/01/2014' end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '10/01/2005', '12/01/2015' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '08/01/2009', '10/01/2012' 
), `project.dataset.amounts` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '02/01/2014' month_year, 100 amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '03/01/2007', 25 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '10/01/2010', 50 
), all_months AS (
  SELECT id, FORMAT_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', month_year) month_year
  FROM `project.dataset.data`,
  UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', start_date), PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', end_date), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) month_year
)
SELECT id, month_year, SUM(IFNULL(amount, 0)) amount
FROM all_months m
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.amounts` a
USING (id, month_year)
GROUP BY id, month_year
```